# Central simple algebras via cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields, galois-cohomology, central-simple-algebras

I am following the book *Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology*, by Gille and Szamuely (I am using the second edition). In section 2.4, the authors remark that the tensor product induces a natural map $\mathrm{CSA}_K(m)\times \mathrm{CSA}_K(n)\to \mathrm{CSA}_K(mn)$. Since we have previously identified degree $n$ central simple algebras split by $K$ with cohomology classes in $\mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K/k),\mathrm{PGL}_n(K))$, there is a corresponding map 
 $$\mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K/k),\mathrm{PGL}_m(K))\times \mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K/k),\mathrm{PGL}_n(K))\to \mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K/k),\mathrm{PGL}_{mn}(K))$$

The authors claim that this corresponding map is the one induced by the natural map $\mathrm{GL}_m(K)\times \mathrm{GL}_n(K)\to\mathrm{GL}_{mn}(K)$. I don't see why this is true. Any help?

Comment: To see the claim, you need to think through how the identification $\mathrm{CSA}_K(m) = \mathrm{H}^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K/k), \mathrm{PGL}_n(K))$ works. So it is hard to answer the question without knowing how well you understand that identification.

Comment: As @TheoJohnson-Freyd comments, the answer to your question is entirely dependent on your picture/explication of the first "identification" map. That is, not all of this is purely dictated by some universal functorial stuff...